# Displaying date portion of timestamp in laravel field

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table data value in my laravel blade:

```
<td>{{$events->updated_at}}</td>
```

which just reads from a database *timestamp* value. It works and displays as it should but the controller is reading the full timestamp, which we need, but in this table data cell I only want to display the date portion.

So instead of 2017-12-27-00:00:00, I just want to show 2017-12-27.

Is there a special way I should go about this in a laravel blade?

Comment: $date = substr($events, 0, 10);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the timestamps in an Eloquent object use the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) class, making formatting easier. So all you have to do is use the Carbon format functions:

```
<td>{{$events->updated_at->toDateString()}}</td>
```

Comment: I like this, but it unfortunately gives me a 'call to member function toDateString on String' error on page load

Comment: I guess `updated_at` isn't being cast as a Carbon class. Try following the instructions on Aaron's answer for typecasting the date (though his quotes are wrong) : `protected $dates = ['updated_at'];`

Comment: Ok so I'd do this in the model?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a Carbon instance, you can use any of it's methods:

```
{{ $events->updated_at->toDateString() }}
```

Or:

```
{{ $events->updated_at->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

Alternatively, you can [create a new accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
public function getUpdatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->updated_at->toDateString();
}
```

And use it in Blade:

```
{{ $events->updated }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated_at attribute should be cast to a Carbon object already before it’s passed to the view, so you can just do

```
{{ $events->updated_at->toDateString() }}
```

If that doesn’t work, in your model do this:

```
protected $dates = [‘updated_at’];
```

Answer (score 0):

With Carbon

```
{{ Carbon::parse($events->updated_at)->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

With localisation (since Carbon 2 (Laravel 5.8))

```
{{ Carbon::parse($events->updated_at)->translatedFormat('d F Y') }}
```